# How do I fix this problem when trying to host my rest api (node.js) on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, heroku

[image]https://github.com/pickypickleapp/herokutest123

Hello I just started learning about Rest API's and I am trying to make my own one and host/upload it on heroku.
I get this error when trying to host. I've tried many solutions and most seem to say its Procfile related but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see a little above your message, you'll probably notice you missed the `dotenv/config` package, referenced in server.js (line 6).  Otherwise, committing the `node_module` is not good practice, instead, commit the file `package-lock.json`. It will ensure that the proper packages, meaning the right code according to the version, will be installed on heroku.

```
npm install --save dotenv
```

Comment: ...but also, don't use `dotenv` on Heroku. That's a _development_ tool for conveniently populating environment variables, and `.env` files shouldn't be committed. Instead, use Heroku's config vars.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand what happens when you load your website to Heroku. It looks for package.json to install dependencies. When you run `npm install` on your machine, that happens only on your machine. Heroku is a different machine, so it needs to install everything too. To see how it happens do the following on your machine.

1. Remove node_modules `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Run `npm install`
3. Go to localhost and see what happens.

If something is wrong you will see an error in your node console.

Also when you put your website on hosting service you do not need to use `nodemon` package, as it is used in development only. Instead of this you want to use `pm2` to monitor your app performance and automatically reload in case it crashes.